# Sed Command Unix. Add a line of space after each command

Tags: shell, unix, sed

Hi am currently writting a shell script. Within the shell script I have a function that uses the sed command

```
Rewordfunction()
{
sed -i 's/The 1st Cat was/The Dog was getting pay 132  /' AnimalReportEmail
sed -i 's/The 2nd Cat was/The Dog was getting pay 232/' AnimalReportEmail
sed -i 's/The 3rd Cat was/The Dog was getting pay 2344 /' AnimalReportEmail
}
```

The sed command is working as intended how I would love to make it so when I email it out it looks like this

```
The Dog was getting pay 132
The Dog was getting pay 232
The Dog was getting pay 2344
```

Rather than this

```
The Dog was getting pay 132 The Dog was getting pay 232 The Dog was getting pay 2344
```

Is there a way to add a line of blank space after each command so I can get the results I want ?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: What your input in `AnimalReportEmail` look like? If it doesn't have any newlines in it already, the output is as expected.

Comment: How about `\n` just before the last `/` in the sed substitution?  (And use `"` (double quotes) instead of single quotes.)

Comment: Show your email sending command also.

Comment: guessing this may be an artifact of MS-Windows file format. If Windows is involved, use `cat -vet AnimalReportEmail`. If you see lines ending with `^M$`, then use `dos2unix AnimalReportEmail`, and re-run your `sed` script. good luck.

Comment: eg, `sed "s/hello/Goodbye\\n/" <<< "hello"`

Comment: Why are you running `sed` 3 times? Don't you know you can execute multiple operations in a single call, with multiple `-e command` arguments?

Comment: You definitively have to show your _input file_ and the copy of your _actual_ `RewordFunction`. For now, the only input file that _might_ have produced that result would have been `The 1st Cat was The 2st Cat was The 3st Cat was`. Which is quite odd? And even so, this input **would not** produce the given output (regarding the _spaces_ at the end of your `sed` expressions)